# Как заменить /lang=ru на /ru в адресной строке?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

У меня есть сайт `http://www.example.com`, и он мультиязычный, когда меняю язык сайта, например на русский, то в адресной строке показывает `http://www.example.com/?lang=ru`, мне надо так чтобы показывало `http://www.example.com/ru` когда меняю язык на русский, как можно это реализовать?

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^lang=en$ 
RewriteRule ^ /en? [R=301,L]
```

редирект работает правильно, и перенаправляет на `http://www.example.com/ru`, но пишет что страница не найдена

Comment: изучить синтаксис правил `RewriteRule` и написать таковое.

Comment: @teran у меня уже есть синтаксис                                                   
`RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^lang=en$
RewriteRule ^ /en? [R=301,L]`, и она перенаправляет на `http://www.example.com/ru`, но пишет что ошибка 404 и страница не найдена

Comment: дак если уже что-то есть, надо это приложить к вопросу. 404 правильно выдает, у вас правило в обратную сторону написано. вы же хотите чтобы в адресной строке было `/ru`, значит входящая строка правила будет `ru`, ее и надо на первом месте указывать, а перенаправлять должно на `?lang=`. Будет у вас что-то вида `RewriteRule ^(ru|en)/?$ index.php?lang=$1` и без `301`

Comment: @teran вроде сделал все по вашему указу, но все равно в адресной строке выводит `lang=ru`

Comment: отредактируйте скрипт переключения языка, чтобы при смене отправлял не на `?lang=ru` а на `/ru`. с этого собственно и над было начинать. Потом бы он стал выдавать вам 404, потому что не знает, что это. а затем вы бы написали это правило перенаправления.